# Accessing application.conf through 'play console'

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

I'm developing a migration script using Scala for one of my Play projects.  This script makes use of the libraries in the Play project, so it resides in the project path.  I use 'play console' to execute the script and it works well.

However, I can't figure out how to retrieve settings from the application.conf there.  play.api.Play.current.configuration throws an error 'java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application'.

Any suggestion of how to get the settings using another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the underlying config library:

```
import com.typesafe.config._

val config = ConfigFactory.load()
```

Or you could start a Play application:

```
import play.core.StaticApplication

new StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))

play.api.Play.current.configuration.get(...)
```

Comment: I did the latter.  Thanks.